# How to find the desktop size from within GVim?

Tags: gvim

I flip between different laptops and desktops a lot, some using external monitors.  Maintaining different vimrc files is unmanageable.  They become fragmented, and customizations that I come to rely on are suddenly available because I am working on a different system.

One such customization is the changing of the Vim window to a thin vertical window abutted against the right edge of the desktop.  That way, I can take notes while partaking in video conferences.  At present, I have a `:GR` command (mnemonic for "Go Right") which sizes and positions the Vim window appropriately, but using hard coded position and size numbers.  If I can get the desktop size from within GVim, then I can calculate these parameters, which means that `GR` can be made to work regardless of what display I am using.

Is there a Vim command that can query the host windowing system for the desktop size?  I primarily work with Windows 10, but I use Cygwin and X-windows.

Comment: At a guess, you could write a function that uses tests like `has('win2unix')` (Cygwin), (not sure about Windows itself or X-windows) and then, depending on what system, query a tool or file or whatever for the information you need. This is actually pretty common to do, I think

Comment: @D.Ben Knoble: OK, thanks.  Looks like there no insulation from the weird (and sometimes wonderful) world of X-windows.

Comment: Does Cygwin and X-windows have the `xrandr` tool? If so, you can use it to get information about the current screen(s). For example, `xrandr --query | grep ' connected primary' | grep -Eo '[0-9]+x[0-9]+'` works on my Xorg system. You can use `system()` to call that from Vim: `let [w, h] = system("xrandr --query | grep ' connected primary' | grep -Eo '[0-9]+x[0-9]+'")->trim()->split('x')` (use `str2nr()` to convert from string to number)

Comment: @MartinTournoij: Cygwin's X-windows does have `xrandr`.  I will use your idea.  Thanks!  Did you want to post this as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Cygwin comes with `xrandr`, you can use this to query information about a screen (all of this also works on e.g. Linux by the way). To get information you can use:

```
% xrandr --query | grep ' connected primary'
eDP-1 connected primary 1536x864+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 276mm x 155mm
```

Which shows I have a screen with a resolution of 1536x864 (it's an odd size because I scale it a bit from the default 1920x1080).

To use this in Vim you can use the `system()` function to call a shell command and `matchlist()` to "grep" the resolution out of there:

```
let [w, h] = system("xrandr --query | grep ' connected primary'")->
    matchlist('\d\+x\d\+')[0]->
    split('x')->
    map({_, v -> str2nr(v)})
```

A somewhat more complete version with some checks so it doesn't error out if the command doesn't exist:

```
fun Resolution() abort
    " Default, in case the command fails.
    let [dw, dh] = [1920, 1080]

    " Get resolution from xrandr, and match the resolution.
    let r = system("xrandr --query | grep ' connected primary'")
    if v:shell_error > 0
        return [dw, dh]
    endif

    let r = r->matchlist('\d\+x\d\+')
    if len(r) == 0
        return [dw, dh]
    endif

    " Split resolution by [width]x[height] and convert the string to a
    " number.
    let [w, h] = r[0]->split('x')->map({_, v -> str2nr(v)})
    if w == 0 || h == 0
        return [dw, dh]
    endif
    return [w, h]
endfun
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in follow-up. I've had to spin up on a few vimscript concepts, such as lambda functions and curly braces.  I haven't cracked the nut on the latter. I found the use of curly braces in `:help eval`, but it doesn't fit your use of it in `map({...})`. Without `{...}`, the underscore is explained in `:help map()`. Can you please provide a pointer to an explanation of the idiom `map({_,...})`? Thanks!

Comment: @user2153235  `map()` calls a function for every item in the list and updates the value with whatever that function returns. You can write a "lambda" function as `{arguments -> function body}. `map` passes the array index and the value, in that order. So for `some_list->map({ idx, value -> str2nr(value) })` it calls `str2nr()` for every value in the list (the return is implied with lambdas). I use the `_` for the `idx` because we don't use that (which isn't "special" in VimScript IIRC, it's just a variable name).

Comment: Thanks again, Martin. It all seems clear, and described in the Vim help. I was just getting side tracked by the missing 1st arguments for `map` when `->` is used to invoke a function -- which is as it should be. I was also thrown by the need for `map`'s 2nd argument to be a 2-argument function (index and value); theoretically, it seems that the mapping function should only be a function of each element's value, regardless of the index. From a practical standpoint, however, it's nice for the mapping function to be able to access the index.

Comment: This has turned out to be way more complicated than I expected.  I resize Gvim into a 60-column window abutted to the left edge of the desktop using `set lines=999 columns=60 | let &lines = &lines -3 | winpos 0 50`.  The `- 3` accounts for the window title bar and the Windows 10 task bar (I use Cygwin).  To position the window along the right edge of the desktop, I then need to subtract the window width from desktop width, but it's tricky to get the window width without [`xdotool`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14170/163540) on Cygwin. I think I'll set this aside for now.