# Get Gvim window width in X-window without xdotool?

Tags: gvim

I have a long-term goal of writing VimScript functions to dock my Gvim window as a thin window abutted to the left or right edge of my desktop.  I am using Windows 10, but with Cygwin's X-Window and Gvim.

Docking to the left seems easier than to the right:

```
set lines=999 columns=60
  " `lines` will be limited to the maximum
  " that fits on the desktop
let &lines = &lines -3
   " The -3 accounts for the window title bar
   " and the Windows 10 task bar
winpos 0 50
   " Position the Gvim window upper left
   " corner by (x,y) coordinates, where (0,0)
   " is the upper left corner of desktop.  The
   " 50 provides space above Gvim for the
   " Windows 10 title bar.
```

After docking to the left, I can dock to the right by [getting the desktop size](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/37965/7041) in terms of pixels, subtracting the width of the Gvim window (in pixels), and setting the x-coordinate of the Gvim window to this difference.

I'm stuck on getting the Gvim window width in pixels.  One way to do this is using [xdotool](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14170/163540) in X-window.  Unfortunately, this is not available in the Cygwin port.  **Is there another way to to get the width of the Gvim window in pixels?**

Comment: AutoHotKey has [WinGetPos](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGetPos.htm); I think that's kind of the "xdotool for Windows". No idea how well that will work with X-Window/Cygwin though. `xprop` can also print the window size, although not in an easily parseable format (e.g. `xprop -id $(xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | grep -o '0x[0-9]*')` for the currently active window, and in the case of Firefox, it also seems wrong, but it's correct for my terminal window).

Comment: From the Bash prompt in an xterm, I get `_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW:  not found`.  That `xprop` query doesn't seem to be [universally available](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395613/why-is-xprop-root-not-returning-net-active-window). I'm not sure if I'm stubborn enough to install a 3rd part Windows hot key and scripting tool and explore its interactions with X-window.  It's not possible to do for several of the machines that I use anyway (user rights).  But I appreciate your pointer to the possibilities.